# How to store a list of phone numbers in Twilio, then return one at random?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm building a phone service with Studio & Functions where a new user is connected with a random previous user. The intended behavior:

1. User texts the service, receives a response from Studio.
2. Studio passes their number to Functions.
   Their number is stored (in an asset? variable? this is where I'm having trouble)
3. A random previous user's number is selected from storage.
4. This user's number is passed back to Studio and deleted from storage. (obviously, this storage is pre-populated with a buffer of several phone numbers, so there's not just one number in the system at a time)

I know how I plan to handle it from there, but what's the best way of storing a list of numbers and selecting from it at random in Functions? Is there some kind of array I can use? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The one product that Twilio has that can do data storage is [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync). It's mostly used for state synchronisation across client applications and powers the Conversations SDK.

But from within a Twilio Function you can use the [Sync REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api) to add items to a [document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api/document-resource) and then also retrieve the document, pick a number from it randomly, and save the document without that number.